# Python object serialization to XML & deserialization from XML

Tags: python, xml, serialization

How I can serialize instance of class to XML file and deserialize back?

---

For example.

I have class "Cat":

```
class Cat:
    __name=''
    __age=0
    __tail_length=0
    __weight=0

    def __init__(self, name, age, tail_length, weight):
        self.__name=name
        self.__age=age
        self.__tail_length=tail_length
        self.__weight=weight
```

Is possible make that?

```
timon=Cat(name='Timon', age=3, tail_length=20, weight=18)
magic_xml_serializer.serialize(destfile='cat-timon.xml', obj=timon)
del(timon)
timon=magic_xml_serializer.deserialize(sourcefile='cat-timon.xml')
print ('yes','no')[type(timon)=='Cat'] #yes
```

If it's possible to do, please write me how. Or just give me link with examples of code. Thanks!

*P.S. Python version 2.7*

Comment: What have you tried to solve your own problem? Also what's up with all of the `__vars`?

Comment: I'm newbie in Python and ask about nice solution of this problem. I have tried to use xml.pickle.

Comment: I'm sorry, newbie or not, you're required to demonstrate effort of your own.

Comment: I think, that simple task like serialization/deserialization with XML can be solved without external libs and with minimum code.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: I can't understand, what is wrong with my class attributes? They are private.

Comment: What's wrong is that you're making your code hard to read for no reason. Plus, you're initialising everything twice. I bet you're a java programmer.

Comment: So, you suggest me don't use private vars? I repeat again, I'm newbie in Python, but I think, in my example class attributes was initialized just once: at "__init__" method occurs assing received values to created variables.

Comment: You initialize on class creation, and on each object creation. This is unnecessary, and repetitive. Also, there's no reason to use private attributes. Indeed, they're more likely to create problems than not.

Comment: Python automatically makes all class attributes without specifier "self" as static?

Comment: Thx for explanation and lot useful info! By the way, I'm not Java programmer =) But very close: .NET and C# are my main toolkit.

Comment: Anyway, python's default serialisation is in a package called `pickle`, which is a binary format. In general, there's no good way to automatically output xml, because no-one can predict what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [spyne](http://spyne.io) for getting xml output over a server (RPC).
spyne is excellent for soap if that is what you want (looking at your C# .NET background)